# TypeScript dynamic generate value type checking

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Suppose I have a generic function that takes raw data, and an array of parsers to generate a simple object

```
function parseData<T extends object>(
  rawData: any,
  ...parsers: Array<{
    field: keyof T
    parser(rawData: any): any
  }>
): T {
  // Loop through and generate object
}
```

And the function call would look like

```
interface ResultData {
  name: string,
  age: number
}
const result = parseData<ResultData>(
  rawData, 
  { field: 'name', parser: nameParser },
  { field: 'age', parser: ageParser }
)
```

The type checking for `field` works beautifully. If I were to put in something that's not `name` or `age`, I get the expected syntax error. I am wondering if there's a way to ensure the parser result is the correct value type for that specific field. For example, I want to receive a syntax error if I try to pass `{ field: 'name', parser: ageParser }` as one of the parsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something close to what you want but it involves adding type parameters which need to be inferred, and since TypeScript doesn't currently allow [specifying some type paremters while allowing others to be inferred](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), (but it's coming [soon](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#33-january-2019)), there's a [trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) you can use to sort of give that to you in the meantime.

First, let's use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) with a [lookup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to generate the union of possible parser types for type `T`, assuming the "raw data" is of type `R`:

```
type Parsers<T, R> = { [K in keyof T]: { field: K, parser(rawData: R): T[K] } }[keyof T];
```

Then we curry the `parseData()` function to the user-specified `T` value, as well as the `R` value corresponding to `rawData`, and the [tuple rest parameter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) type `P` corresponding to `parsers`.   The implementation of the function is left to you:

```
declare function parseData<T extends object>(): <R, P extends Parsers<T, R>[]>(
  rawData: R,
  ...parsers: P
) => T;
```

Now let's see if it works:

```
interface ResultData {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

const resultDataParse = parseData<ResultData>(); // T is now ResultData

// call parser:
const result = resultDataParse(
  "hello",
  { field: 'name', parser: (x: string) => x + "!" },
  { field: 'age', parser: (x: string) => x.length }
);
```

This looks good, and should fail if you switch things around:

```
const oops = parseData<ResultData>()(
  "hello",
  { field: 'name', parser: (x: string) => x + "!" },
  { field: 'age', parser: (x: string) => x + "!" } // error, string not number
)
```

It will not fail if you leave out a parser:

```
const noError = parseData<ResultData>()(
  "hello",
  { field: 'name', parser: (x: string) => x + "!" },      
)
```

so either you want the output to be `Partial<T>` instead of `T`, or you want to somehow constrain `parseData()` to require all parsers; but that wasn't in the question and I've got to run. ‍♂️

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Beautiful solution, I learned a lot from the examples. Thanks!